# Create a button that DELETES an item from MongoDB (Mongoose Node.js express.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a CRUD project where a user can insert data with forms and it's all stored in mongoDB. Everything seems to work fine but I can't find a solution on how to create a button that deletes a specific item from a DB.

//Code for Delete button (which is within the article when you click on it)

```
<form action="/delete/:id" method="post">
<button type='submit' class="btn btn-lg">Delete</button>
</form>
```

//This is my solution so far

```
app.post('/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
  Post.deleteOne((err) => {
    if (!err) {
      res.redirect('/')
    }
  })
});
```

**So the problem is when I click Delete, it deletes the first item from the DB. I need it to delete the page where I clicked the button on.**

[before Delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWBMB.png) |||
[after Delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dve5m.png)

Comment: It does not deliver the ID received as params to MongoDB. Add a filter to the first parameter of deleteOne.

Comment: Do this `Post.deleteOne({_id: req.params.id},  (err) => { ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, check if a provided ID is the actual object ID then you must pass that ID into the command:

```
app.post('/delete/:id', async (req, res) => {
  await Post.deleteOne({_id: req.params.id})
  return res.redirect('/')
});
```

Comment: Could you please mark it as accepted?

Comment: For delete HTTP requests use `app.delete(...)`.

Comment: I get this error here..  `const castError = new CastError();
                    ^

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value ":id" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Post"`

Comment: if you could, please take a look at my code. Maybe you'll see what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance! https://github.com/karina4840/daily-journal-site-4840

Comment: This error happens if the provided ID is not valid object ID please validate that using this method: 

var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
ObjectId.isValid(<PASS YOU ID HERE>);